# send file with jquery post without page refresh mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to post File by AJAX post with jQuery without page refresh, but I have a problem.

I get this error in jquery:  `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

**HTML**

```
<table id="tblQuadrupletRange" >***

    <tr>
        <td >
            <input id="QuadrupletRangeFile" name="QuadrupletRangeFile" type="file" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">
            <a href="#" id="InsertQR">Insert</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
$(document).on('click', "#InsertQR", function (e) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("SetQuadrupletRangeList")';

    var photo = document.getElementById("QuadrupletRangeFile");
    var file = photo.files[0];
    $.post(url, { file:file }, function (data) {
        if (data == "True") {
            //do something
        }
    });}
);
```

**Controller C# code**

```
[HttpPost]
public void SetQuadrupletRangeList( HttpPostedFileBase file)
{    
    HttpPostedFileBase objpostFile = file;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about your form encoding type, is it `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`?

Answer (score 3):

The post must be replaced with ajax call and be updated as follows:

```
data = new FormData();
data.append('file', file);
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,  // do not process the data as url encoded params
    contentType: false   // by default jQuery sets this to urlencoded string
    type: 'POST',
    success: function ( data ) {
       alert( data );
    }
});
```

From jQuery docs:

> processData (default: true) Type: Boolean By default, data passed in
>   to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a
>   string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting
>   to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If
>   you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this
>   option to false.